# Merging one tf.data.Datasets with every other element of another one

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to merge two `tf.data.Dataset` so that only every other sample of the first one is combined with the other, *without* any sample lost.

For example, let's have two lists of numbers:

```
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
ds10 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10, 60, 10)
```

I want to combine them so that samples from the second are added to the first, but only every other time:

```
0, 11, 2, 23, 4, 35, 6, 47, 8, 59
```

There is a `zip` method that enables to merge two datasets, but it does so by drawing a sample from each -- not combining samples would mean dropping a sample from `ds10`, which is not what I want.

I could continue from there, and zipping `ds10` with "dummy" samples that are dropped during the zip with `ds1`, but it doesn't look very efficient.

Is there an efficient way to do that, without dropping samples (either real or "dummy")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def combine(pair,to_add):
    combined = [pair[0], pair[1] + to_add]
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(combined)

ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(10,60,10)

combined = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1.batch(2),ds2)).flat_map(combine)
```

Explanation:

First, batch `ds1.batch(2)`.This produces `[(0,1), (2,3), ...]`.
Zip this to the other dataset to get `[((0,1),10), ((2,3),20), ...]`.
Undo the batching with `flat_map` and in the process combine every `(a,b)` with `c` in each `[((a,b),c), ...]` like `[(a,b+c), ...]`.
The result is then flattened to remove the braces and you get `[0, 11, 2, 23, 4, 35, 6, 47, 8, 59]`.
Batching and unbatching like this is a common pattern when dealing with several `tf.data.Dataset`s.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Is it ok to create a `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` in a call to `flap_map`, performance-wise? It looks as if a new `Dataset` is created for each sample pair, so that is rather unusual.

Comment: It depends, really. It is the case that `from_tensor_slices` does nothing more than just assigning it in the memory of the dataset object. This exact operation is lightweight. If you, for example did the same for a huge tensor or a large dataset, it would be bad.

Comment: @user209974 And, of course, it looks really cool :) I've learned that pattern in [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Hands-Machine-Learning-Scikit-Learn-TensorFlow/dp/1492032646).